# Power BI Matrix, ColumnB Divided By ColumnA

Tags: powerbi

I have a matrix in Power BI that looks like:

```
Year  | CountA | CountB

2016  | 242593 | 201999

2017  |  91335 |  59042

Total | 333928 | 261041
```

I would like another column that produces this, where Div = CountB / CountA

```
Year  | CountA | CountB | Div

2016  | 242593 | 201999 | 83.27%

2017  |  91335 |  59042 | 64.64%

Total | 333928 | 261041 | 78.17%
```

I've tried creating new columns and new measures, but bringing it into the matrix will auto-sum the percentages.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add a measure

```
Div = SUM(Table1[CountB])/SUM(Table1[CountA])
```

Set format to `Percentage`,

[image]

Comment: Would you know if this would work on Direct Query mode ?

Comment: @donquijote You can add measures in DirectQuery mode, so I don't see why not.

Comment: This worked perfectly, and it failed earlier because I didn't add it in Direct Query mode. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Though it shouldn't matter if it's DirectQuery or not.

Comment: @user5226582 you are totally right, it was not working for me on direct query because i defined as calculated column not measure

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Query Editor.
Click on the Add Column Tab.

Add a custom column and set it to;

```
  Number.ToText(Number.Round(([Count B]/[Count A])*100,2)) & "%"
```